# Numbers | Email | Applescript

Tags: email, applescript, iwork

I would like to create a numbers spreadsheet. In that spreadsheet I want to have COL A Email Col B City Name COL C Other City Name and so on. I will manually enter that data in.

What I would like to do next is have applescript go through line by line in the numbers spreadsheet and send an email to each person in the column. I would like to use the other variables in the subject or body of the email.

Any help would be appreciated! I am a novice at best programmer. I know a small bit of python but am new to applescript.

Pseudo code (maybe?)

```
tell numbers to open spreadsheet
repeat for each line of spreadsheet
tell mail to create email
for address COL A
for subject "Hello (COL B) I need the following Information (COL C)
for email Body "Blah Blah Blah (Col D) blah blah."
send email 
end repeat
```

Email Function

```
on email(a, b, c, d)
    set recipientName to a
    set recipientAddress to b
    set theSubject to c & " --> " & d & "Shipment"
    set theContent to a & ", if you would like assistance with your shipment moving from " & c & " to " & d & " , or any other shipment you may have, please let me know. We have drivers available in your Area of Operations ready for pick up."

    tell application "Mail"

        ##Create the message
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

        ##Set a recipient
        tell theMessage
            make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}

        ##Send the Message
            send

        end tell
    end tell
    end email

    my email(COL A, COL B, COL C, COL D)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I hacked together! I'm a newbie so be gentle. Improvements and critiques are greatly appreciated!

```
on email(emails, names, origin, destination)
    set recipientName to names
    set recipientAddress to emails
    set theSubject to "c" & " --> " & "d" & "Shipment"
    set theContent to names & ", if you would like assistance with your shipment moving from " & "c" & " to " & "d" & " , or any other shipment you may have, please let me know. We have drivers available in your Area of Operations ready for pick up."

    tell application "Mail"

        ##Create the message
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

        ##Set a recipient
        tell theMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}

            ##Send the Message
            send

        end tell
    end tell
end email

on recipientNames()
    set y to 1 as string
    tell application "Numbers"
        activate
        open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:TYPKRFT:Desktop:Form.numbers"
        tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
            set myNames to {}
            repeat with i from 1 to the count of rows
                set x to "B" & y
                set myNames to myNames & the value of the cell x
                set y to y as integer
                set y to y + 1
                set y to y as string
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell

    set itemsToDelete to {"missing value", "Name", missing value, "stop"}

    set cleanNames to {}

    repeat with i from 1 to count myNames
        if {myNames's item i} is not in itemsToDelete then set cleanNames's end to myNames's item i
    end repeat
    return cleanNames
end recipientNames

on emailAddress()
    set y to 1 as string
    tell application "Numbers"
        activate
        open alias "Macintosh HD:Users:TYPKRFT:Desktop:Form.numbers"
        tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
            set myEmails to {}
                repeat with i from 1 to the count of rows
                set x to "C" & y
                set myEmails to myEmails & the value of the cell x
                set y to y as integer
                set y to y + 1
                set y to y as string
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell

    set itemsToDelete to {"missing value", "Email", missing value, "stop"}

    set cleanEmails to {}

    repeat with i from 1 to count myEmails
        if {myEmails's item i} is not in itemsToDelete then set cleanEmails's end to myEmails's item i
    end repeat
    return cleanEmails
end emailAddress

set a to emailAddress()
set b to my recipientNames()


set reps to count of a
set x to 1
repeat reps times
    set emails to item x of a
    set names to item x of b
    my email(emails, names)
    set x to x + 1
end repeat
```

Comment: Also Its not finished there are two remaining functions but they will be nearly identical to the recipientNames function